# Adding elements to an array in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

I have this code where I want to add 10, 11 and 12 to array arr.

```
my @num=(0,1,2);
my $i=10;
for my $d (@num){
   if (defined($d)) {
      my @arr;
      $arr[$d] = $i;
      $i=$i+1;
      my $dvv=dump(\@arr);
      print "**** $dvv \n";
   }
}
```

The output is:

```
**** [10]
**** [undef, 11]
**** [undef, undef, 12]
```

Why is only the last element of array defined?

Comment: It is always good to maintain `use strict and use warnings`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you have the declaration of the array within the loop, it will re-create it each time, removing any values that would have been placed in it on previous iterations of the loop.

You should declaure `@arr` before the loop if you want the values to stay:

```
my @arr;
for my $d (@num) {
    ...
}
```

And because of this line:

```
$arr[$d];
```

`$d` is the position defined by the other array (0, then 1, then 2). So it puts  the value of `$i` in that position in the array, and puts values before to `undef`.

Answer (score 14):

AntonH's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34891552/82262) addresses the specific problem with your specific code, but there are actually ways to rewrite your code that would avoid the problem entirely. A more "Perlish" way to accomplish the same thing would be:

```
my @arr;

for my $i (0 .. 2) {
    push(@arr, $i + 10);
}
```

Or:

```
my @arr = map { $_ + 10 } 0 .. 2;
```

Or just:

```
my @arr = 10 .. 12;
```