# Unable store all the outputs to array in Perl

Tags: perl

I am reading the lines from a file and input it to commands.

```
open my $handle, '<', $path_to_file;
foreach  $line (<$handle>) {
  my @output  = `cmd`;
```

I want to store each output to array. But unable to store it , it overwrites the previous value

Comment: Your code does move each output to another array. Did you mean that you want to store *all* the outputs in a single array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding elements to an array in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891472/adding-elements-to-an-array-in-perl)

Comment: yes i want to move all the output in single array , when i run the above code it over writes the previously stored value . My objective is store all values in array and print as 
A - 2
B -3

Comment: @user9437648 You would probably benefit from reading a Perl tutorial; this is fairly basic stuff.

Comment: So ... have you tried anything? What kind of answer are you looking for? Just some piece of code you can copy/paste in your program?

Comment: open my $handle, '<', $path_to_file;
foreach  $line (<$handle>) {
  my @output  = `cmd`;
 print $output[1];
 
it does not print anything , when i print $output[0] it prints 2 values as below
2
3

when i ask to print $output[1]  i need 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
open my $handle, '<', $path_to_file;
foreach  $line (<$handle>) {
  my @output  = `cmd`;
} # I added this closing brace.
```

You have a couple of problems here.

Firstly, each time around the loop, you are declaring a new, empty, instance of `@output`. So declare the variable outside of the loop.

```
my @output;
open my $handle, '<', $path_to_file;
foreach  $line (<$handle>) {
  @output  = `cmd`;
}
```

There's still a problem here though. You're overwriting the whole of `@output` in each iteration of your loop. You want to add your data to the end of `@output`. So instead of assigning a value to the array, you should `push()` a new element to the end of the array.

```
my @output;
open my $handle, '<', $path_to_file;
foreach  $line (<$handle>) {
  push @output, `cmd`;
}
```

**Update:** As Borodin points out in a comment, `push()` imposes list context on the backticks, so they'll return a list where each element is a single line from the output of your command. You might want to tame that behaviour by either ensuring that each execution of the command returns a single string (perhaps with embedded newlines):

```
push @output, scalar `cmd`;
```

Or create a two-dimensional array where each element of `@array` is a reference to another array containing all of the lines of output from a single execution of the command:

```
push @output, [ `cmd` ];
```

Comment: Perhaps `push @output, scalar qx/cmd/` or `push @output, [ qx/cmd/ ]`?

Comment: @Borodin: Thanks for the suggestions. Updated my answer.